# Time of splitting and encoding video with ffmpeg increases exponentially

Tags: video, audio, ffmpeg, h.264, aac

I'm trying to split a video by subtitles and encode into .mp4(h.264/aac) using **ffmpeg**, but it takes so much time! First pieces of video are splited and encoded really fast, but for each iteration time increases, and so 40 min video takes all night or more. Small 3 min video takes max 10 mins.

command for splitting and encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.avi -ss 00:00:0(time of sub start) -t 0:0:3(time of sub duration) -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -bf 0 -f mp4 filename.mp4
```

ffmpeg version N-34849-g07c7ffc (last, i think)

How I can make it faster? Are there, maybe, some magic arguments for ffmpeg or some hacks?

Comment: I suspect that in order to process the -ss it has to decode the entire file up to that point?

Comment: Hmm. If yor are right, how i can decode only that part, which i need?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter order matters. Try putting the start time `-ss` parameter first.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:0(time of sub start) -i filename.avi -t 0:0:3(time of sub duration) -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -bf 0 -f mp4 filename.mp4
```